# String contains IP isn't correctly detecting first three octects of IP

Tags: vb.net

I have a string.. i'm trying to figure out if it contains 10.10.

```
'Dim s As String = "10.100.1.1"
'If s.Contains("10.10.") Then
'    MessageBox.Show("Contains")
'Else
'    MessageBox.Show("Doesn't contain 10.10.")
'End If
```

Should I be doing this a different way? Perhaps Starts with? Or Regex?

Comment: Does 172.10.10.42 meet the criteria of your test?

Comment: There's a spurious dot at the end of "10.10.".

Comment: The first two octects, I use to determine what site (location) the hardware is at, that's why I leave the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code

```
Private Function IsPartOf10dot10(ips As String) As Boolean
    Dim rv As Boolean = False
    Dim IP As System.Net.IPAddress
    If System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ips, IP) Then
        Dim b() As Byte
        b = IP.GetAddressBytes
        If b.Length = 4 Then
            If b(0) = 10 AndAlso b(1) = 10 Then
                rv = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return rv
End Function
```

Pass an IP address as a string to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Shared IPRangeStart As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.10.0.0")
Private Shared IPRangeEnd As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.11.0.0")

Private Function IsIPInRange(IP As String) As Boolean
    Dim address As IPAddress
    Return IPAddress.TryParse(IP, address) AndAlso 
        address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork AndAlso
        address.Address >= IPRangeStart.Address AndAlso
        address.Address < IPRangeEnd.Address
End Function
```

And, of course, you can easily add overloads for accepting custom ranges.